# Can we keep different environment test data files in cypress

Tags: cypress

The application i am working on has 3 different environments. so is there a way to use a specific test data files for each environment( QA/STG/PRD) when running tests. I know we can use *cypress.env* file to specify environment related data but i couldn't figure out how to specify different file when running in different environments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to choose which files your cypress will run according to the .env, but you can put your test content inside an IF, so even if cypress runs the test file, everything will be inside one IF that if not satisfied will not perform actions.

```
describe('Group of tests', () => {
    it('Test 1', () => {
        if(env == 'dev') {
            // Your test here
        } else {
            /* put something here so that cypress doesn't 
            throw an error claiming the test suite is empty. */
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a package [cypress-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-tags) that might suit your needs.

> Select tests by passing a comma separated list of tags to the Cypress environment variable CYPRESS_INCLUDE_TAGS

```js
describe(['QA'], 'Will tag every test inside the describe with the "QA" tag',
  function () { ... });

it(['QA'], 'This is a work-in-progress test', function () { ... });
```